# Access VirtualBox Debian Guest on Windows Host

Tags: debian, windows, virtualbox

I am running Oracle VirtualBox with Debian as guest OS on a Windows 7 host.  I have installed Apache and specified the following two network adapters in VM:

1. Bridge
2. Host-only w/ the same IP set as below.

My interfaces network settings on the Debian VM are:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto eth1 
    iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.110
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

which all seems to work well enough via `ping` test between guest and host.  However, when I try to browse to my guest instance in a web browser `http://192.168.1.110` I keep getting a 404 message. Any help would be appreciated.

Thinking that the ifconfig results my help, I will include those also here:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:7a:1a:35  
      inet addr:192.168.1.106  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe7a:1a35/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:252 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:19 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:25417 (24.8 KiB)  TX bytes:1765 (1.7 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:56:3d:90  
      inet addr:192.168.1.110  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe56:3d90/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:231 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:21945 (21.4 KiB)  TX bytes:578 (578.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: 404 is 'document not found' error, what are your apache logs saying on your Debian VM?

Comment: Drav.  This sounds like a good approach.  Can you recommend which log to check?  I am assuming it is one in /var/log  Thanks.

Comment: Correct, by default Debian logs to `/var/log/apache2`, and you should find an `error.log` in there.

Comment: I checked the error.log and the most recent messages in there are regarding PHP and Apache ".. resuming normal operations".  I will add my ifconfig results as they may help folks in understanding my configuration.  Again any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the IP address of the address of the Windows host? If it is on the 192.168.1.x network, your ping and browser might not be hitting the VirtualBox. Easy test: power down the VirtualBox and try your ping again.

Comment: Yes, the IP address of the Windows host is 192.168.1.105 and when I power down the VirtualBox the ping still works.  However, I wouldn't expect it to.  Which makes me think that you are correct in that I am not actually hitting the VirtualBox.

Answer (score 3):

Successfully pinging the "powered off" VirtualBox is the give-away: the guest machine needs to be on a different IP sub-network than the host machine belongs to. VirtualBox will handle the routing between the guest network and the host network and provide a proper address and gateway to the guest with a DHCP server seen only by the guest.

You don't explain why you've added the static eth1 interface, but I'm guessing it is so you can reach the guest machine on a known address. Drop the static configuration, see what network the guest is assigned and then you can use that network (often 10.0.*.*) for the provisioning of a static address if you need to afterwards.

The box that you are reaching at 192.168.1.110 is living on the same subnet as the host and may well be a real physical device on your host's network.

Comment: I set up the static eth1 interface because I was following the instructions at http://blog.xoundboy.com/?p=586.  In these instructions the author is explaining how to make a VM  accessible by the windows host even when laptop is “offline”.  When I drop the static config, as you suggest, I get just the DHCP issued IP, and this IP does work in a browser on the host machine.  This is great but I am now at a loss then how to assign a static IP.

Comment: @geoderek I'm sorry, your question and that article have exceeded my knowledge of Windows networking. It does appear that you'd only need a bridged interface and if I was trying to hack this together, I'd probably grab the IP off the guest machine and add it to `%sysdir%/etc/hosts` but even if that works, its a kludge.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out by the following metnod. The IP you are going to give eth1 should be very similar to the IP auto-assigned by VirtualBox to the second adapter that was attached to.  To see this IP go to File > Preference > Network > Edit (Host-only Network Details). Here you will see the IP that was auto-assigned to the Host for the second adapter.  You will use this IP modifying the last octet to be different e.g. .10 instead of .1